# Partial fraction composition of $f(x) := \frac{2-3x}{(x-1)(x-\frac{1}{2})}$

Tags: calculus, power-series, partial-fractions

We want to develop the function

$$f(x) := \frac{2-3x}{(x-1)(x-\frac{1}{2})}$$

into a power series at $0$.

What I'm struggling with is the partial fraction decomposition.

The idea is that we split $f(x)$ into

$$\frac{2-3x}{(x-1)(x-\frac{1}{2})} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x-\frac{1}{2}}$$

What I don't get is how we can solve this for $A$ and $B$.

I tried multiplying both sides with $(x-1)(x-\frac{1}{2})$ and that would give

$$2-3x = A (x-\frac{1}{2}) + B(x-1)$$

but how do we continue from this?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144987/discussion-on-question-by-mathisdifficult-partial-fraction-composition-of-fx); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since $(x-1), (x - \frac{1}{2})$, are relatively prime, there is a solution and furthermore, $deg(A) < deg(x-1)=1, deg(B) < deg(x-\frac{1}{2})=1$.

So $A, B$ are rational numbers.

Writing

\begin{align}
2−3x=A(x - \frac{1}{2})+B(x−1)
\end{align}

and evaluating at $x=\frac{1}{2}, x= 1$ gives $A=-2, B=-1$

Comment: We must not duplicate answers. There are already a lot of similar posts on this site. Like [the proposed duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279525/partial-fraction-decomposition-help-now)

Comment: And how exactly did we evaluate? We literally have $3$ unknowns

Comment: okay, I can remove it. Although just FYI I'm not able to comment due to lack of points.

Comment: @mathisdifficult No, it's supposed to be true for all x (well, when the denominators aren't zero at least).  There are 2 unknowns.